# duplicate paths found in tmux mac

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux

i have a mac terminal where i have a tmux session running.  When i call my env variable, i get duplicate paths that repeat.  I tried various solutions here but none seem to work.  I'm using zsh shell by default.

What i tried:

1. Went to my zprofile and included the following line:

```
if [ -f /etc/profile ]; then
    PATH=""
    source /etc/profile
fi
```

Didn't work.

2. Went to my profile and have the following code, still didn't work:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    PATH=""
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

My bashrc file:

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"
```

All the above files are located in /etc/ directory.

All my env variables are in .zprofile.

Thanks

Comment: What is `if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ];` meant to check?

Comment: i have no idea, its just there in that file.  should i delete it?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to set `PATH=""` before sourcing `/etc/profile` (It's not clear there's any reason to explicitly source it, either.)

Comment: Your `bash` configuration files should be irrelevant if you are using `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this worked for me.

tmux set-option -g default-command zsh

i put above statement in my terminal